# "dev" version of package is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: software-installation, repository

I am new to Ubuntu and keep butting up against errors, such as this:

```
Package libpng12-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it: libpng12-0
```

and

```
E: Unable to locate package subversion
E: Package 'git-core' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'autoconf' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libtool' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libxml2-dev
E: Unable to locate package libgeos-dev
E: Unable to locate package libpq-dev
E: Unable to locate package libbz2-dev
E: Package 'proj' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package munin-node
E: Unable to locate package munin
E: Unable to locate package libprotobuf-c0-dev
E: Unable to locate package protobuf-c-compiler
E: Unable to locate package libfreetype6-dev
E: Package 'libpng12-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libtiff4-dev
E: Unable to locate package libicu-dev
E: Unable to locate package libboost-all-dev
E: Unable to locate package libgdal-dev
E: Unable to locate package libcairo-dev
E: Unable to locate package libcairomm-1.0-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libcairomm-1.0-dev'
E: Unable to locate package apache2
E: Unable to locate package apache2-dev
E: Unable to locate package libagg-dev
```

when I want to do this:

`sudo apt-get install subversion git-core tar unzip wget bzip2 build-essential autoconf libtool libxml2-dev libgeos-dev libpq-dev libbz2-dev proj munin-node munin libprotobuf-c0-dev protobuf-c-compiler libfreetype6-dev libpng12-dev libtiff4-dev libicu-dev libboost-all-dev libgdal-dev libcairo-dev libcairomm-1.0-dev apache2 apache2-dev libagg-dev`

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Woah, that's a lot of packages you're installing at once!  I assume you're following a guide to setup something specific, like an Apache server?

There are two things that are likely to be going on, one or both:

1. Your package list is outdated, and simply needs to be refreshed.  Simple fix:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   Then try your installations again.
2. Slightly more likely, Ubuntu has more specific versions of these packages available, but doesn't know to install them given the names you've typed out.  If you're willing to invest a few minutes, I would install Synaptic, a graphical package manager, with the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install synaptic
   ```

   Synaptic will allow you to search for packages by name, and allow you to select which version you'd like to install, if there are multiple available.  Launch Synaptic, allow it a moment to build its search index (the search bar in the program will tell that's what's going on), then try locating your packages one at a time. Once you've found a package you'd like, click on its checkbox, and select *Mark for installation*.

   Some packages you select will require that you install dependencies; that is fine.  You may even find that some of the packages you were trying to install on the command line get automatically selected for you, because one of the packages you've selected depends on it.

If you decide to go the synaptic route, start with the package `apache2`, because it will have many dependencies.

Once you've selected everything you'd like to install, click on the *Apply* button and let Synaptic do its thing.  Good luck!